# Unity vs Libgdx vs Cocos2d-x

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, unity-game-engine, libgdx, game-engine

I'm a Android and a Software Programmer.

Currently I know three languages C++, C#, Java. Now I want to make games as well. After searching the Internet I got the names of these three engine, so which engine should I use for game development for mobile?

Please, provide the reason as well.

Requirements:
I want to use it for 2d and few ideas are
A platformer shooter
A RPG game
A strategy game

Important:
I am indie dev and I am quite bad at graphics designing, and I have 0 budget

And you.can also recommend any other lib or engine

Comment: This question is indeed off-topic as answers will be primarily opinion-based.

Comment: Why ask if you knew it was off topic?

Comment: But still as secons opinion

Comment: There are already some other very similar questions here. My vote goes for libGDX as I never had any problems with it and the community is AWESOME. However I haven't used the other two.

Answer (score 52):

**cocos2d-x**

1. Opensource.
2. Less community support but good support on other sites (3k search results on stackoverflow).
3. Many Famous games like 2048,BADLAND are developed using cocos2d-x
4. The minimum size of game developed on cocos2d-x can be as low as 1.5MB
5. Supports both 2D and 3D but mainly used for 2D.
6. C++ is mainly used for development.
7. Supported Platforms: Android, Tizen, Windows 8, Windows Phone 8, Linux, Mac OS X, iOS

**libgdx**

1. Opensource.
2. Good community support as well as on other sites (9k search results on stackoverflow).
3. Some famous games like Ingress,Apparatus are developed on libgdx.
4. Supports both 2D and 3D.
5. Java is mainly used for development.
6. Supported platforms: Windows, Linux, Mac OS X, iOS, Android, BlackBerry, Java Applet, Javascript/WebGL

**Unity**

1. Paid.
2. Huge Community support and huge support on other sites (15k search results on stackoverflow)
3. Many famous games like monument valley, Temple Run 2, Angry Birds Epic are developed on Unity.
4. Supports both 2D and 3D but mainly used for 3D only because developing 3D games on unity is very easy as compared to other platforms.
5. The minimum size of game developed on unity is around 8MB.
6. C#,unityscript is mainly used for developemnt.
7. Supported Platforms: Android, Apple TV, BlackBerry 10, iOS, Linux, Nintendo 3DS line, OS X, PlayStation 3, PlayStation 4, PlayStation Vita, Unity Web Player (including Facebook), Wii, Wii U, Windows Phone 8, Windows, Xbox 360, and Xbox One

I hope it helps

Comment: There are some famous games using libgdx https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bithack.apparatus (500k-1M) https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nianticproject.ingress (5M-10M) for example

Comment: Or https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hyperkani.sliceice&hl=ro

Comment: So which should I use to work with

Comment: @BhavyaMaroo It depends on your command over the 3 languages. If you are good in c++, go for cocos2dx and so on. If you are thinking of 3D game then go for unity.

Comment: Now you can also consider a Cocos2d fork for .NET called CocosSharp. Where you can develop in C# and F#. http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/game_development/cocossharp/

Answer (score -2):

It pretty much depends on what you kind of game you want to make. 
Unity is more for 3d games like FPS or gun games, while cocos2d-x and libgdx are for anime-like games.

You can browse the stores for each platform and see what kind of games are created by that platform.

Also note cocos2d and libgdx are open source while Unity is closed.

Comment: I am looking for both 2d and 3d

Comment: So can you tell the pros and cons and technical facts and the games made by these engines and libs

Comment: The 3D API of libGDX is not that bad. Pretty easy and powerful as long as you are not trying to achieve FarCry 3 graphics.

Comment: Actually, all three platforms are well organized in general. **If any**,  Unity is more for 3D games. So the important difference is more about the politics. **In my opinion**, libgdx is the most convenient library as it is open source and a lot of information is available for it.